# Limit of an integral of sin(x)

Tags: integration, limits, analysis

I need to calculate
$\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\left(\int _0^{\infty \:}\left(sin\left(x\right)\right)^ne^{-x}\:dx\right)$

**My attempt**

Use the dominated convergence theorem, then $| (sin(x) e^{-x} |\leq e^{-x} = e^{-x}$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} dx = -e^{-x} |_{o}^\infty = 1 < \infty$ then $g(x)=e^{-x} \in L^{1}$

by the other side $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} (sin(x)^{n} e^{-x}=0$ such that $sin(x)<1$

then $|sin(x)^{n}|<\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}=0}$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} (sin(x))^{n}=0$

finally $\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow \infty} |(sin(x))^{n} e^{-x}|\rightarrow _{n\rightarrow\infty} \lim \limits_{a\rightarrow \infty} 0 = 0$

I'm not sure if it's correct, otherwise any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you change $'\sin x<1$' to '$|\sin x| <1$ except for countably many $x$, hence for almost all $x$ your proof is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\sin(x))^n=0$. The limit is undefined, in fact.

Instead, you could use integration by parts (twice) on $$I_n=\int_0^\infty\sin^n(x)e^{-x}dx$$ to show that $$I_n=\frac{n^2-n}{n^2+1}I_{n-2}$$

Since $\frac{n^2-n}{n^2+1}<\frac{n^2-n}{n^2}=\frac{n-1}n$, we have $I_n<\frac{n-1}n I_{n-2}$. For even $n$ (for example), this shows that

$$\frac{I_n}{I_0}<\frac{1\times3\times5\times...\times(n-1)}{2\times4\times6\times...\times n}\\
=\frac{1\times2\times3\times...\times n}{(2\times4\times6\times...\times n)^2}
=\frac1{2^n}\frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!^2}
$$

This can be shown to approach $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ using, for example, Stirling's formula.

Comment: The limit is zero almost everywhere and bounded everywhere, which would be enough for an application of dominated convergence.